# Using regex to find start and end of paragraphs in text file

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text file which looks like below:

```
Current File: week-28\gcweb.txt (=>) ########## Old File: week-27\gcweb.txt (<=)



2019-07-21 13:20:42 ip-172-17-3-71=>
2019-07-17 13:27:12 ip-172-17-3-71<=
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Current File: week-28\gcckup.txt (=>) ########## Old File: week-27\gcckup.txt (<=)



2019-07-21 13:20:46 ip-172-17-2-101=>
2019-07-17 13:27:14 ip-172-17-2-101<=
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
```

The text from `Current File` to `------` indicates one para or one part. I need to get all these separately and then apply some other operations on it. I tried using regex to get the entire text starting from `Current File`.

The regex I used is:

```
\bCurrent File\b.+
```

My question is: how can I select the whole text of one para? Having little experience with regex I am hoping to get something like this:

```
Current File: week28\gcweb.txt       Old File: week-27\gcweb.txt
2019-07-21 13:20:42 ip-172-17-3-71   2019-07-17 13:27:12 ip-172-17-3-71
```

While `(=>)` and `(<=)` are simply indicators for current and old. So I tried using this to get the file path `\bCurrent File\b.+(=>)` but this gives `(=>)` as group.

I need help with extracting the strings so that I can apply the rest of the operations on them after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can for instance design some expression that'd look like,

```
Current File:[\s\S]*?(?=--)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6YARHs/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/6YARHs/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

#### Edit:

For getting `.txt` path, we can likely use an expression similar to:

```
Current File:\s*(\S+\.txt).*Old File:\s*(\S+\.txt)[\s\S]*?(?=-{4,})
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/bW1d4W/1/)

```js
const regex = /Current File:\s*(\S+\.txt).*Old File:\s*(\S+\.txt)[\s\S]*?(?=-{4,})/gm;
const str = `Current File: week-28\\gcweb.txt (=>) ########## Old File: week-27\\gcweb.txt (<=)



2019-07-21 13:20:42 ip-172-17-3-71=>
2019-07-17 13:27:12 ip-172-17-3-71<=
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Current File: week-28\\gcckup.txt (=>) ########## Old File: week-27\\gcckup.txt (<=)



2019-07-21 13:20:46 ip-172-17-2-101=>
2019-07-17 13:27:14 ip-172-17-2-101<=
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Now I  need to extract the path for Current and old file. I think that would we a easy task. Just one more thing If you could help. After the File paths. the lines below have some dates/text which end with `=>` or `<=` . In need to put them under current file or old file. I am thinking to simply use endswith() function. What do you suggest

Answer (score 1):

Another option to get the filenames in a group followed by the match could be:

```
Current File: (\S+\.txt)[^O]*(?:O(?!ld File)|[^O])+ Old File: (\S+\.txt).*(?:\r?\n(?!--).*)*(?=\r?\n--)
```

- `Current File: (\S+\.txt)` Match Current File: and capture the filename in group 1.
- `[^O]*` Match 0+ times any char except O
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `O(?!ld File)` Match O, assert what is directly on the right is not `ld File`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^O]` Match any char except O
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `Old File: (\S+.txt)` Match space, Old File: and capture the filename in group 2
- `.*` Match any char except newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!--)` Match a newline and assert what is on the right is not `--`
  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?=\r?\n--)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is a newline and --

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE49UK/1)

```js
const regex = /Current File:[ \t]*(\S+\.txt)[^O]*(?:O(?!ld File)|[^O])+ Old File:[ \t]*(\S+\.txt).*(?:\r?\n(?!--).*)*(?=\r?\n--)/gm;
    const str = `Current File: week-28\\gcweb.txt (=>) ########## Old File: week-27\\gcweb.txt (<=)



2019-07-21 13:20:42 ip-172-17-3-71=>
2019-07-17 13:27:12 ip-172-17-3-71<=
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Current File: week-28\\gcckup.txt (=>) ########## Old File: week-27\\gcckup.txt (<=)



2019-07-21 13:20:46 ip-172-17-2-101=>
2019-07-17 13:27:14 ip-172-17-2-101<=
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------`;
    let m;

    while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
        });        
    }
```